# Invalid Templates files in magento2 during admin menu and route

Tags: xampp, magento2, magento-2.3

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Bss_CreateMenuBackend::helloworld.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'content_schedule_block1'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Bss_CreateMenuBackend::helloworld.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'content_schedule_block1'

```
#1 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Template.php:129]
#2 Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1097]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1101]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:671]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:557]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('content_schedule...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:533]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content_schedule...') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content_schedule...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:488]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content_schedule...', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content_schedule...', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:585]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:535]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:488]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:585]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.col', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:535]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.col') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.col') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:488]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.col', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.col', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:585]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('admin.scope.col....', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:535]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('admin.scope.col....') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('admin.scope.col....') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:488]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('admin.scope.col....', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('admin.scope.col....', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:585]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.contai...', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:535]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.contai...') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.contai...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:488]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.contai...', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.main.contai...', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:585]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:535]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.content') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:488]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.content', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:585]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:535]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:488]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:585]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:535]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:488]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('backend.page', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:585]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:535]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:488]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:954]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:492]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php:258]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005a145ea0000000002a77c2a8#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php:171]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005a145ea0000000002a77c2a8#) called at [generated\code\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php:193]
#55 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000005a145ea0000000002a77c2a8#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php:141]
#56 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php:24]
#57 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php:261]
#58 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000005a145eab000000002a77c2a8#) called at [index.php:39]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently, you have not asked a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the file is available on path and check code is valid as per php and html stucture:

```
app/code/Bss/CreateMenuBackend/view/adminhtml/templates/helloworld.phtml
```

which is specified in layout file with block name "content_schedule_block1"

Answer (score 0):

The example is wrong. You should follow this doc: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html.

If you want to fix it. You only need to change resource="Magento_Backend" in menu.xml.